# C# - How to put variables into second column ListView

Tags: c#, listview, button, count

I have 2 forms, form1 and form2.
form1 has 2 buttons, btnVanilla and btnConfirm.
form2 has a listView, listView1.

On form1 when vanilla is clicked once, it should show "1" in Quantity column next to Vanilla. 
But at the moment it is showing "1" underneath vanilla. How do I move it across onto the next column?

There is a screenshot which shows what I mean.

form1

```
public partial class form1 : Form
{
    private string vanilla = "Vanilla";
    private List<string> _values = new List<string>();

    public form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int vanillaCount = 0

    public void btnVanilla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_values.Contains(vanilla))
        {
            _values.Add(vanilla);

        }

        vanillaCount++;
    }

    private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2 frm2 = new form2(_values, vanillaCount);
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();

    }

}
```

form2

```
public partial class form2 : Form
{
    private List<string> _values;

    public form2(List<string> _values)
    {
        this._values = _values;
    }
    public form2(List<string> passedValues, int vanillaCount)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (var item in passedValues)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
      listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text = vanillaCount.ToString();
    }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that this line

```
 listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text = vanillaCount.ToString();
```

is correct? You aren't creating subitem anywhere, it should be like

```
listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Add(vanillaCount.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution for your actual problem:

```
public Form2(List<string> passedValues, int vanillaCount)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // This line let you show more Columns
            listView1.View = View.Details;

            // Define your needed Columns 
            listView1.Columns.Add("Item-Name", -2); //(the width with -2 means, that the column will be autosized)
            listView1.Columns.Add("Quantity");

            foreach (var item in passedValues)
            {
                // Create a new ListViewItem "Vanilla", add your needed Subitems like Quantity, Price, ...
                var newItem = new ListViewItem(item);
                newItem.SubItems.Add(vanillaCount.ToString());

                // add the new Item to your ListView 
                listView1.Items.Add(newItem);
            }
        }
```

But you should create a list with a own object-type like

```
public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem use like this:

```
ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem(); 
row.SubItems.Add(value.ToString()); 
listview1.Items.Add(row);
```

you repeat the second row as many times as you have columns in the listview